# How to write in text file by variable using python 2.7

Tags: python

I have stored the string in a variable. And I want to append it to a text file. How can I achieve this?

```
 def readyaml(abs_read_path,):
        with open(abs_read_path, 'r') as stream, open("instanceinput.txt",'w') as fnew: 
            try:
                content = yaml.load(stream)
                instance = content['instance']
                dump = instance[0]
                print dump
                fnew.write(dump)
            except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
                print(exc)
        stream.close()
        fnew.close()

    readyaml(abs_read_path)
```

Comment: You may want to read the docs on [file operation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), as well as [PEP 434](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/). You will notice that you do not have to `close` a file obeject when using a context manager. The actual error is obviously due to `dump` not beeing a string. Did you check the type of `dump`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use the append method as **Vikas & Mayur has mentioned** and also when writing to a file convert it to a sting object:

Example:

```
def readyaml(abs_read_path,):
        with open(abs_read_path, 'r') as stream, open("instanceinput.txt",'a') as fnew:
            try:
                content = yaml.load(stream)
                instance = content['instance']
                dump = instance[0]
                print dump
                fnew.write(str(dump))  # CONVERT TO STRING OBJECT
            except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
                print(exc)
        stream.close()
        fnew.close()

    readyaml(abs_read_path)
```

Comment: Thank you.. It Worked for me..

Answer (score 2):

use `a` instead of `w` :

```
 with open(abs_read_path, 'r') as stream, open("instanceinput.txt",'a') as fnew:
```

Comment: I am getting the same error File "C:\Users\*****\Desktop\ParseScript\readingYAML.py", line 31, in <module>
    readyaml(abs_read_path)
  File "C:\Users\*****\Desktop\ParseScript\readingYAML.py", line 25, in readyaml
    fnew.write(dump)
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object

Answer (score 1):

You can use `'a'` or `'a+'` instead of `'w'`

`'a'`   The file is created if it does not exist.
     Open for writing and appends the data.

`'a+'`The file is created if it does not exist. 
       Open for both reading and writing and appends the data while writing.